# my JQuery Image Replace Script isn't working

Tags: jquery

I have a page of Divs, and I identify Every Other Div as a "Header" (i.e., class="HeaderOn" or class="HeaderOff", to specify if the Header is Green (on) or Grey (off).

Since I Hide all Div contents of any Div after a div with Class="HeaderOff", I wanted to put a "+" icon in front of the Text of that Div, and a "-" icon in front of the "HeaderOn" div text.

I use this jquery to accomplish that, and it works fantastically.

```
$("div .HeaderOff").prepend("<img src='Images/Expand.jpg' align='absbottom' />");
$("div .HeaderOn").not(':first').prepend("<img src='Images/Collapse.jpg' align='absbottom' />");
```

This puts the "+" or "-" icons on the page in front of the Text of the "Header" divs.

Then I call this script:

```
$("div [id$='Header']").click( function () {
$(this).next('div').toggle('slow');
if ($(this).next('div').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Collapse.jpg');
} else {
    $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Expand.jpg');
}
});
```

This script is designed to Bind a Click function to all "Header" divs, and making it so if you click on the Header, it Hides or Shows the contents of the Next Sibling Div.  This part works fine.  It's the next part that does NOT work.  It is supposed to check the "Visible" state of the Next Sibling Div, and if it is Visible, change the "+" icon to a "-" Icon, and if it is NOT Visible, change the "-" con to a "+" Icon.  Again, this part does NOT work.  And I cannot figure out why.  It will change it from a "+" to a "-", but it will NOT change from a "-" to a "+"

Here is the entire Document Ready Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("div .HeaderOff").prepend("<img src='Images/Expand.jpg' align='absbottom' />");
    $("div .HeaderOn").not(':first').prepend("<img src='Images/Collapse.jpg' align='absbottom' />");
    $("#ResponseMessage").toggle();
    $(".DatePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    $("div [id$='Header']").click( function () {
        $(this).next('div').toggle('slow');
        if ($(this).next('div').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Collapse.jpg');
        } else {
            $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Expand.jpg');
        }
    });

    $("#PartNumber").on ("keyup",  function (evt) {
        $("#ResponseMessage").text('KeyUp Updated').toggle().delay(500).toggle('slow');
    });

    $(".OnChange").on ("change",  function (evt) {
        $("#ResponseMessage").text('Change Updated').toggle().delay(500).toggle('slow');
    });

});

</script>
```

and a sample of the Div Structure:

```
<div id="InventoryPhotosHeader" class="HeaderOff">
Photos
</div>
<div id="InventoryPhotos">

</div>
<div id="CrossSellHeader" class="HeaderOff">
CrossSells
</div>
<div id="CrossSell">

</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been struggling with this.

Comment: can u create a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net ... i got confused reading you question actually...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).next('div').toggle('slow');
```

this makes it slowly go from visible to invisible.  since it is first, it will, by the time you check with `if ($(this).next('div').is(':visible'))` always be visible, whether its .01% opacity or 99.99%.  You should move it to after the check occurs.

```
    if ($(this).next('div').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Collapse.jpg');
    } else {
        $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'Images/Expand.jpg');
    }
     $(this).next('div').toggle('slow');
```